# Python from LaTeX: Strange Networkx/Graphviz error

Tags: tikz-pgf, input, automation, python, shell-escape

It is hard to give a minimal example, because Python3 with some packages is needed. I want to call Python from LaTeX, here is an example how I want to do it (--shell-escape is needed):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \input{|python3 ./core/dijkstra_automated_exercise.py}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to call a Python script, which prints a graph automatically:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import string
import random
import pygraphviz

def draw_digraph(adj_matrix):
    # Drawing the graph
    n = len(adj_matrix)
    G = nx.DiGraph(np.matrix(adj_matrix))
    layout = nx.planar_layout(G)
    layout = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')
    
    layout = {i: ([layout[i][0]//10, layout[i][1]//10]) for i in layout}
    # General tikz options
    tikz_opt = 'scale = 1, font= \Large'

    # Node Options
    default_node_opt = 'shape=circle, draw, line width=1.5pt'
    char_labels = list(string.ascii_uppercase)[0:n]
    node_labels = {i: char_labels[i] for i in range(0,n)}
    node_opt = {i: "circle, draw" for i in range(0,n)}

    # Edge Options
    default_edge_opt = "bend left=20, line width=1.5pt"
    edge_opt = {}
    edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight')
    edge_label_opt= {(i,j): "fill=white, circle, draw, very near start, font=\large" for i in range(0,n) for j in range (0,n)}

    # General to_latex_raw documentation
    # to_latex_raw(G, pos='pos', tikz_options='', default_node_options='', node_options='node_options', node_label='label', 
    # default_edge_options='', edge_options='edge_options', edge_label='label', edge_label_options='edge_label_options')
    return nx.to_latex_raw(G, 
                           pos = layout,
                           tikz_options = tikz_opt, 
                           default_node_options = default_node_opt,
                           node_options=node_opt,
                           node_label = node_labels, 
                           default_edge_options = default_edge_opt, 
                           edge_options = edge_opt,
                           edge_label=edge_labels,
                           edge_label_options = edge_label_opt
                           )

def generate_random_digraph(V, E):
    adj_matrix = [[0 for j in range(V)] for i in range(V)]
    edges = set()
    while len(edges) < E:
        start_node, end_node = random.randint(0, V-1), random.randint(0, V-1)
        if start_node != end_node:
            edges.add((start_node, end_node))
    for start_node, end_node in edges:
        adj_matrix[start_node][end_node] = 1
    return adj_matrix

adj_matrix = generate_random_digraph(6,6)

print("\\section{The First}\n")
print((draw_digraph(adj_matrix)))
```

Now I have a problem, which I do not understand. `layout = nx.planar_layout(G)` works, but the result is bad. So I want to call `layout = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='neato')`, **but** after this line, LaTeX can not access/get the output of the python script. I really do not understand, why this error occurs. The terminal output of the script is still correct and I could include this output in LaTeX and it works, but such a solution would not be as elegant, as I want it to be. Can someone explain me, why I can't access the output directly from LaTeX and how to fix it?

Comment: can you show the full error from`!` to `?` from the log?

Comment: There is not error, it just does nothing. I use Texifier under MacOS, but I assume, that it does not work with a different IDE. Interestingly both version do not work, if I compile directly from the terminal. But there is no error message either...

Comment: I'd add some print to the python so stdout is never empty and you can see where it's failing, if it really silently fails I'd have to guess your graphiz call is putting an end of file marker into the stream somehow, but I have python but not  those graphiz libraries so can't test

Comment: I tried debugging with prints :D It breaks directly after the graphviz call. Every print before that is accessed by latex, every print after that is not accessed. Do you have an idea for a fix, if it is putting a end of file marker?

Comment: to test  run the script outside tex and redirect stout  to a file then look in the file or a hex dump for ctrl d or ctrl z or some such, if that is the issue you should be able to filter that from python